# R shiny how to generate a ui to select which data sets to open after being uploded to the shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app and I have to generate a dynamic ui that contains the names of the data sets already uploded in order to select which one to open and work on my current code for this part (not the full code) is : (in the server part)

```
lst<-c()

observe({
     observeEvent(input$store,{                 

                         print(lst)

                         a<-getname()

                         lst<-c(lst,a)

                         updateRadioButtons(session,"dfstore",
                                            label="DFstore",
                                            choices=as.list(lst),
                                            selected="")      
                                            })


                                         })
```

So every time I click on the button store the lst goes back to NULL and since it is NULL it succed only in kepping the last name how can I make it keep the last value before getting the new name?

Thanks.

Comment: did you look into `renderUI()`?

Comment: I did and I could generate some for other purpos but my problem is how to keep all the name not only the last one please prvide me the link you are talking about